# Expression for ith Chern class in terms of trace of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, characteristic-classes

In *Topology, Geometry, and Physics* by Nakahara, the following is given:
$$ c_0 (F) = 1\\
c_1(F) = \frac{i}{2\pi}\text{tr}(F)\\
c_2(F) = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{i}{2\pi})^2(\text{tr}(F)\wedge\text{tr}(F) -\text{tr}(F\wedge F))
\\ ... \\
c_k=\frac{i}{2\pi}\det(F)$$

I understand where the expressions for $c_0$ and $c_k$ come from, but from where the other ones come from? Is there an analytical formula for $c_i (F)$ given $1<i<k$?

Comment: This is just an application of Newton-Girard formulae, right?

Comment: Yes, of course, the usual definition is as the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of the matrix-valued $2$-form $\dfrac i{2\pi} F$. As you suggested, these symmetric functions can be rewritten using the Newton formulas.